# Dynamically add textareas into form in meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to insert `textarea`'s into a form in meteor. This is the template I currently have:

```
template(name="guide_create")
    .format-properly
        form.form-horizontal(id="guideForm" method="POST" action="/create-guide")
            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="title") Title
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control(name="title" id="title")
            .form-group
                .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                    .checkbox
                        label
                            input(name="is_public" type="checkbox")
                            p Make your guide public
            .form-group
                label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="cards") Cards
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control(name="cards" id="cards")
        center
            button.btn.btn-primary#add-section(style="margin-bottom: 15px;") New Section
            each sections
                +section

template(name="section")
    textarea.new-section(type="text" uniqid=uniqid)
    button.remove-section Remove
```

The first template, *guide_create*, has the form and the second template *section* includes the `textarea`. This is how I currently add my `textarea`'s dynamically to the page:

```
Template.guide_create.onCreated(function() {
  Session.set('sections', []); // on page load, set this to have no inputs
});     

Template.guide_create.events({
    'click #add-section': function () {
        var sections = Session.get('sections');
        var uniqid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
        sections.push({uniqid: uniqid});
        Session.set('sections', sections);
    }
});

Template.guide_create.helpers({
    sections: function () {
        return Session.get('sections'); // reactively watches the variable
    }   
});
```

I hope this is possible somehow, and I want to have these `textarea`'s now included in my form, that when I submit the form, the content of those `textarea`'s is also submitted. The newly created `textarea` is currently outside of the form and I want to change that. Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your sections are appearing outside of you form because they are being added in the template outside of the form group. Try moving them up into the form group, something like this?

```
        .form-group
            label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="cards") Cards
            .col-sm-10
                input.form-control(name="cards" id="cards")
                each sections
                +section
        center
            button.btn.btn-primary#add-section(style="margin-bottom: 15px;") New Section
```